# IIS URL Rewrite if link does not match

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

```
    <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mywebsite.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://mywebsite.com/"
                  redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

That code works:
if it's website.com, it links you to another one

but, I want it so if it's NOT website.com, it links you

Comment: So basicly instead of if the url matches it links u i want it if i DOES NOT MATCH

Comment: Have you tried to prefix your pattern with "!?" -> ^!?mywebsite.com$